# Android Landscape mode cutting off my last EditText

Tags: android, android-layout

I've got a problem in my application.

My layout contains:

- ImageView
- Button
- Four EditText

When I change the emulator in landscape mode the ScrollView goes to the third EditText. The last EditText is not displayed in landscape mode.

**My layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="235dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:id="@+id/formulario_foto"
            android:background="#00A8EC"
            android:src="@drawable/person"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="56dp"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:id="@+id/formulario_foto_button"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom='true'
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/formulario_foto_button"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:hint="Nome"
        android:id="@+id/editTextNome" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="E-mail"
        android:id="@+id/editTextEmail" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:hint="Endereço"
        android:id="@+id/editTextEndereco" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Telefone"
        android:id="@+id/editTextTelefone" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: You have defined your relative layout height 235 dp but combined height of it's child are 256 dp ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `ScrollView` does not respect the margin of its child. This behavior has been noted in

- [Android ScrollView not respecting child's bottom margin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22884169/3565972)
- [Scrollview doesn't scroll to the margin at the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17124680/3565972)
- [Scrollview extends beyond screen bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16880311/3565972)

The workaround is to wrap your `LinearLayout` in a `FrameLayout`, ie.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    ...
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

This is slightly inefficient, since it uses an extra `ViewGroup`. If you are able to do so, the more efficient solution would be to use `paddingTop` on your `LinearLayout` instead of the `layout_marginTop`, ie.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="60dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
...
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change linear layout height to wrap_content

Comment: I made the change but the same problem continues =[