# How to set margins to dynamically created UI

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

I need to set margin to dynamically created UI. I want to add margin to LinearLayout.

Below is my code

```
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            viewPager = (ViewPager) container;      
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
            this.layoutInflater = inflater;
            scrollView = new ScrollView(getActivity());
            linearLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
            linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            layoutParams.setMargins(15, 15, 15, 15);
            scrollView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);   //add this
            scrollView.addView(linearLayout, layoutParams);

    //adding few UI controllers dynamically by method call to here


            return scrollView;
        }
```

I tried many ways but nothing works. Currently, it is not adding space/margin as per given dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(layoutParams instanceof MarginLayoutParams)
{
    ((MarginLayoutParams) layoutParams).topMargin = 15;
    ((MarginLayoutParams) layoutParams).leftMargin = 15;
    //... etc
}
```

Comment: I think the answer from rafsanahm.. serves your need since my solution is just to set margin to elements which cant be directly set. Anyway, i guess you want your whole view (scrollview wraps linearlayout) with margin.

Answer (score 0):

you need to call `scrollView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);`

also set `Layoutparams` to your `Scrollview` and Inner `LinearLayout`

in your code :

```
 scrollView = new ScrollView(getActivity());
scrollView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
scrollView.setFillViewport(true);

linearLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) scrollView
        .getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.setMargins(15, 15, 15, 15);
scrollView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);   //add this
scrollView.addView(linearLayout, layoutParams);
```

Comment: maybe he want to have a margin between the scrollview and the linearlayout? ;)

Comment: Not worked for me. Layout remains same & not adding margin from any side

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add margins to `LinearLayout`, you need to create `LayoutParams` of the same type of the parent, so:

```
scrollView = new ScrollView(getContext());
linearLayout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
ScrollView.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ScrollView.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
// I recommend you to set resolved size as margins, not pixels like you are doing here.        
layoutParams.setMargins(15, 15, 15, 15);
scrollView.addView(linearLayout, layoutParams);
```

**EDIT**

Remember to add the `ScrollView` to your layout adding `LayoutParams` to it.
For example in a `Fragment` (you are using `getActivity()` so i suppose you are in a `Fragment)`:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(getActivity());
    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    layoutParams.setMargins(15, 15, 15, 15);
    scrollView.addView(linearLayout, layoutParams);
    scrollView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    return scrollView;
}
```

Comment: Not worked for me. Layout remains same & not adding margin from any side

Comment: Have you added the ScrollView to the root view?

Comment: My ScrollView is the root view

Comment: @VVB And have you added it as rootView, returning it in Fragment#onCreateView() or Activity#onCreate() ?

Comment: May be wrong but I'm returning linearLayout inside onCreateView()

Comment: @VVB That's wrong, in that case the LinearLayout will be the root view, you have to return the ScrollView with the change on LayoutParams that i wrote. You have also to add new layout params to the ScrollView of type ViewGroup.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142360/discussion-between-vvb-and-fondesa).

Answer (score 0):

As per this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22884169/android-scrollview-not-respecting-childs-bottom-margin):

```
scrollView.setFillViewport(true);
```

This forces the childview to stretch to the parent scrollview. Then you can set the margins that will add space after filling the scrollview.